# R, ggplot2 add legend with different data frames (of different sizes)

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm trying to make a simple geom_point plot using ggplot2, but I cannot get a legend to appear. I have two data frames I am plotting from that are different lengths (~2000 rows vs ~6000 rows).

I have tried adding things like 'scale_shape_manual(values=c(21, 23)' to get it to pop up, but this has not worked. I have also tried adding 'shape = 21' into aes and 'shape = 23' into aes for their respective geom_point calls, but I got the error 'Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale'. Thanks for any help! See example of code below:

```
x1 = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
y1 = c(0.44, 0.64, 0.77, 0.86, 0.91)
x2 = c(0, 1)
y2 = c(0.42, 0.61)
df1 = data.frame(x1, y1)
df2 = data.frame(x2, y2)

g<- ggplot(df1, aes(x = (df1[,1]), y = (df1[,2]*100))) +
  geom_point(colour = 'black', size = 5, fill = 'blue', shape = 21) +
  geom_point(data = df2, aes(x = df2[,1], y = (df2[,2]*100)), 
             colour = 'black', size = 4, fill = 'white', shape = 23) +
  xlab("Consecutive Dry Years") + ylab("Percent") + ggtitle("Plot") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 100)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=0:20) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(21, 23), 
                     name="My Legend",
                     labels=c("Simulated", "Historical")) +
  #   scale_fill_manual(values=c('blue', 'white'), 
  #                      name="My Legend",
  #                      labels=c("Simulated", "Historical")) +
  #   scale_colour_manual(values=c('black', 'black'), 
  #                     name="My Legend",
  #                     labels=c("Simulated", "Historical")) +
  theme_bw()
g
```

Comment: what problem are you having?....your code runs and produces a nice plot

Comment: The plot does not produce a legend. I can't seem to figure out how to get the legend to appear.

Comment: you are doing it all wrong..for a legend to appear there should be a categorical variable that different your data. the two data frames are exactly alike more over you are just plotting the points..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my ggplotting, I always put my data into one dataframe. I sort of remember somebody saying that there is conflict with specifying different colors across geoms. I think this code gives you the idea:

```
df3 = data.frame(type=c(rep("sim",5), rep("his",2)), x = c(x1,x2), y=c(y1,y2))
g = ggplot(df3, aes(x=x,y=y*100)) + geom_point(aes(color=type)) + geom_line(aes(color=type)) +
  xlab("Consecutive Dry Years") + ylab("Percent") + ggtitle("Plot") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 100))
g
```

[image]

Comment: Very cool, very simple. I don't know why I didn't think about "stacking" my data like that. It's hard to go from the default R plotting paradigm to the ggplot paradigm. Thanks!